# How to configure Spring-boot front-end plug-in for npm?

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, maven, pom.xml

I've developed I have a Reactjs/Spring-boot project based on [this](https://developer.okta.com/blog/2018/07/19/simple-crud-react-and-spring-boot) tutorial.

It works great, but now I'd like to convert it from yarn to npm. Specifically, pom.xml, which uses [this maven front-end plug-in](https://github.com/eirslett/frontend-maven-plugin) to copy the front-end files into a static directory in the jar.

Here's the explanation of how the front-end plugin works from the tutorial link:

```
To build and package your React app with Maven, you can use the frontend-maven-plugin and Maven’s profiles to activate it. Add properties for versions, and a <profiles> section to your pom.xml.

<properties>
    ...
    <frontend-maven-plugin.version>1.6</frontend-maven-plugin.version>
    <node.version>v10.13.0</node.version>
    <yarn.version>v1.12.1</yarn.version>
</properties>

<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>dev</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <spring.profiles.active>dev</spring.profiles.active>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>prod</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>copy-resources</id>
                            <phase>process-classes</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/classes/static</outputDirectory>
                                <resources>
                                    <resource>
                                        <directory>app/build</directory>
                                    </resource>
                                </resources>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
                    <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${frontend-maven-plugin.version}</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <workingDirectory>app</workingDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>install node</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>install-node-and-yarn</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <nodeVersion>${node.version}</nodeVersion>
                                <yarnVersion>${yarn.version}</yarnVersion>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                        <execution>
                            <id>yarn install</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>yarn</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                        </execution>
                        <execution>
                            <id>yarn test</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>yarn</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <phase>test</phase>
                            <configuration>
                                <arguments>test</arguments>
                                <environmentVariables>
                                    <CI>true</CI>
                                </environmentVariables>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                        <execution>
                            <id>yarn build</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>yarn</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <phase>compile</phase>
                            <configuration>
                                <arguments>build</arguments>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
        <properties>
            <spring.profiles.active>prod</spring.profiles.active>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

As you can see, there are two profiles - a short one for "dev" and a longer one for "prod". The one for "dev" just sets the profile property for Spring to "dev". However, the one for "prod", besides setting the active profile for spring to "prod", also copies resources to the target static build directory.

I've modified the pom.xml to include npm instead of yarn as specified in [the plugin's instructions](https://github.com/eirslett/frontend-maven-plugin/blob/master/README.md).

Here's the updated pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.okta.developer</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-app</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>my-app</name>
    <description>My App</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <frontend-maven-plugin.version>1.6</frontend-maven-plugin.version>
        <node.version>v10.13.0</node.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-jose</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- For Java 8 Date/Time Support -->
        <!--test without this, originally from example online poll program -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!--<dependency>-->
        <!--<groupId>com.h2database</groupId>-->
        <!--<artifactId>h2</artifactId>-->
        <!--<scope>runtime</scope>-->
        <!--</dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.oshi</groupId>
            <artifactId>oshi-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.4.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>dev</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <spring.profiles.active>dev</spring.profiles.active>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>prod</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>copy-resources</id>
                                <phase>process-classes</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/classes/static</outputDirectory>
                                    <resources>
                                        <resource>
                                            <directory>app/build</directory>
                                        </resource>
                                    </resources>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
                        <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>${frontend-maven-plugin.version}</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <workingDirectory>app</workingDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>install node and npm</id>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>install-node-and-npm</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <nodeVersion>${node.version}</nodeVersion>
                               </configuration>
                            </execution>
                             <execution>
                                <id>npm install</id>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>npm</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <!-- Optional configuration which provides for running any npm command -->
                                <configuration>
                                    <arguments>install</arguments>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>

                            <execution>
                                <id>npm run build</id>
                                    <goals>
                                        <goal>npm</goal>
                                    </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                   <arguments>run build</arguments>
                                 </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
            <properties>
                <spring.profiles.active>prod</spring.profiles.active>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
```

I run the build with the following command:

```
mvn clean install
```

However, the generated jar file doesn't contain the javascript classes that are in the original:

```
  created: BOOT-INF/classes/static/static/js/
 inflated: BOOT-INF/classes/static/static/js/main.97726d59.chunk.js.map
 inflated: BOOT-INF/classes/static/precache-manifest.08a003d745774e918490c427df8ec1e1.js
 inflated: BOOT-INF/classes/static/static/js/1.e10b24ed.chunk.js
 inflated: BOOT-INF/classes/static/asset-manifest.json
 inflated: BOOT-INF/classes/static/static/js/runtime~main.229c360f.js.map
 inflated: BOOT-INF/classes/static/static/js/1.e10b24ed.chunk.js.map
 inflated: BOOT-INF/classes/static/static/js/runtime~main.229c360f.js
 inflated: BOOT-INF/classes/static/static/js/main.97726d59.chunk.js
 inflated: BOOT-INF/classes/static/manifest.json
 inflated: BOOT-INF/classes/static/service-worker.js
```

It may have to do with the renaming of the goals, but I'm not really clear why the copy isn't happening. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I had apparently misconfigured something for npm. I didn't see it at first because of all the test output. But when I ran

```
mvn -DskipTests package
```

I could see the error messages. I reran the conversion to npm (delete yarn.lock, then run "npm i").  It seems to have worked, although there are some ugly looking warnings.